# How to call a function from another function, but keep all of the types for that specific function

Tags: typescript

I have use case, where I want to register multiple functions, and then call them from another function.

Here's the code

```
const combineFunctions = <T extends Record<keyof T, T[keyof T]>>(funcs: T) => {
  return (key: keyof T, params: Parameters<T[keyof T]>): ReturnType<T[keyof T]> => funcs[key](params)
}

interface AddNumbersArgumentsType {
  a: number
  b: number
}

type AddNumbersReturnType = number

const addNumbers = (params: AddNumbersArgumentsType): AddNumbersReturnType => {
  return params.a + params.b
}

interface CombineStringWithNumberArgumentsType {
  c: string
  d: number
}

type CombineStringWithNumberReturnType = string

const combineStringWithNumber = (params: CombineStringWithNumberArgumentsType): CombineStringWithNumberReturnType => {
  return params.c + params.d
}

const funcs = {
  addNumbers,
  combineStringWithNumber
}

const funkies = combineFunctions<typeof funcs>(funcs)

const a = funkies('addNumbers', [{ // Here Paramters util function forces me to send an array
  // Here it should autocomplete only correct params from AddNumbersArgumentsType
  // But it gives me an option of all arguments all functions take
}]) // => Return type is not gotten correctly, but is a combinations of all functions return types
```

Main problems being

- `Parameters` util forces me to use an array while I just want to get the type of params
- Arguments autocomplete for all params from all functions instead of taking argument types specific to the function
- Same problem with return type as with arguments

[You can see the code running here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=99&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBKC2AjAlmApgMQK5mFZ4EMAvDADwAqMaAHlGmACZEBKaoATo2QNZoCeIAGYwKAGlEBtPoJEUAugD5FACiE5gEAFyiAlCUUwA3gFgAUDBgc0ULBzAwVMnTOGiJABwCGHL-G0wAAo%20fjZoHBCU0gJuCoq6Omy29hT8HmhRrnJKBjDquBDR-PIq3r7%20uuYAvubmqPQcQl7AaDAAgoyMAHJYSOEQbRwA5r0MUBCp6cbmll46YL2I4TMwiPOLy2Y1ZuZQaa0d3RsRSXZgk62kC30ctWagkLBenT03RKSlIf46h69LEYMRvAxhN9gl2i9jhBTil9rlTBYrDYzjAyn4IAA6LwwADUqK%20mMQ1Tu9XCTRaMAAwiAkKg0ABlKAcVBDADqyCgAAs-uFAaMwOMLtNEcAdNBmWAhitGOsbsSdmY9lNqbT0IyJWyOdzjjDznDSOKWXcHtA4DSUGqmSz2VyeRwSI40d8qea6errVq7XzgQLQelwSqLQyrZKbdqbrqhcRDAjLNZkg4nZjgLj8eVMYx5eYTbB8poHbGYM8jm8xCsEEH3aHPccs-dCLmcDxkGh3mbVZgNPhCGQlWg3HmIKpB5UFTmiw78s3WyoAOTFu0QWcSSRGGAAenXMAAEuFWsFyg0iFh8AAbPJdggOIQgDgtIjAmBQEAwCAMRhFhw%20Xz8Fabnd7jAHKvpyIBYKeH5eCeIAIB4p5hDA4CnvwZocNYeBpuieQcDSEIlv8AzDPygr7H%20W4AEInkBsBDMgABurYwI%20XgOCAHjdqxIheKe54%20ECIJFjxF64BxRBQF4fDVPI%20j-tGMC6k%20cLIEQYAgDRan0A4nDoVAyESIgVHKROFaoF4omIVxQl5uZ8Yon2EBAA)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra type parameter on the inner function to capture the actual key passed in, and use that instead of `keyof T` to index into `T`. That will bake ts resolve the actual function being passed in.

`Parameters` returns a tuple of parameters (there could be more) but you can use tuple and rest parameters to fix this.

```
const combineFunctions = <T extends Record<PropertyKey, (...a: any[]) => any>>(funcs: T) => {
  return <K extends keyof T>(key: K, ...params: Parameters<T[K]>): ReturnType<T[K]> => funcs[key](...params) 
}

///.....
const funcs = {
  addNumbers,
  combineStringWithNumber
}

const funkies = combineFunctions<typeof funcs>(funcs)

const a = funkies('addNumbers', {a: 1, b: 1}) // all type cheked
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=29#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-m7WlrqbVAvSIApgCy2QNK4wzR4fbB2rZ3SXoZ84dIqQhYzmE3mvo3wYQWzgIsg0PC-TbMDZ8IQyJaYm0bBALK2IPpvWONO72pPp3IAOSdsMQE+yZxqGAARlkd3vw30QA)

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. TIL about PropertyKey!

Comment: @KristjanVool It's defined as `keyof any`, it just a union of any possible key types (`string | number | symbol`)